# Detectar qual tag que está sendo selecionada

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá!
Eu tenho uma função do jquery que é disparado por duas tags ("select" e "input")
como no código abaixo:

```
$('.checkout-wrapper').on('blur', '.woocommerce-shipping-fields input, .woocommerce-shipping-fields select', function () {

});
```

Tem como eu saber qual destas tags que está chamando o evento por meio do this ou alguma função jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma solução para isso com THIS sim.

Ficaria assim:

```
var tagName;
$('.checkout-wrapper').on('blur', '.woocommerce-shipping-fields input, .woocommerce-shipping-fields select', function () {
    tagName = $(this).prop("tagName");
});
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado mesmo amigo!